# Unable to parse a list of values into a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, feature-extraction

So I need to parse a list of values in python and one-hot encode them for feature engineering. Following is the value from one sample of the 'amenities' column of my featureset.

```
x = {"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Essentials,"Hair dryer",Iron,"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"}
```

The problem here is that this has both curly braces '{}', as well as values which should be in double quotes but are not  (see: Kitchen, Heating in the example above). If I could convert the above to a string, then I know how to remove the braces and split them into a list.

I need to convert the above into a list of items where the values that are not in double quotes become strings.

Comment: What is the type of `x`? A set?

Comment: @excaza It looks like text from a file - Kylo can you confirm this?

Comment: x is just a variable i used. The data is just the following: {"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Essentials,"Hair dryer",Iron,"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"}

Comment: Does it really have those braces? Without, it would be a valid line from a CSV file.

Comment: It does have those braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data looks corrupt. However, the easiest way of doing it would be to remove the double quotes, then split according to commas (I have eluded the curly braces part as it can be easily removed too):

```
s = '"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Essentials,"Hair dryer",Iron,"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"'

print(s.replace('"','').split(","))
```

result:

```
['Wireless Internet', 'Air conditioning', 'Kitchen', 'Heating', 'Family/kid friendly', 'Essentials', 'Hair dryer', 'Iron', 'translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50']
```

Of course, if the data contains commas, you're toast, since there's no way to distinguish commas in fields from separator commas, because of missing quotes... (else it would be a breeze with `ast.literal_eval` parsing)

Full stripping of the curlybraces stuff needs a little more dirty work, but doable:

```
s = 'x = {"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Essentials,"Hair dryer",Iron,"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"}'

print(s.replace('"','').split("{")[1].rstrip('}').split(","))
```

Comment: splitting on comma won't work if any of the individual values have a comma in them. They don't in this example, but I'm guessing there's more data to be processed than just this one line.

Comment: there's no way to tell if comma is a separator or not. If there are commas in the data, then the input isn't parsable. the input data is clearly at fault here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you're right, the input data is at fault. This is just one sample out of 99000. Since I'm going ahead with the assumption that the comma is a separator, your solution was spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the data may still be parseable, if all of the values with commas in them have quotes, which is what I'm guessing. It looks like quotes only appear with values that aren't single words.